# Why isn't any sound playing when a button is clicked in my C#/XAML UWP application?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp

I am trying to use C# and XAML to create a simple app for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). When I run it, my program is supposed to display a button that will play a sound using speech synthesis when clicked. The button shows up when I run the program, but does nothing instead of following the command.

Here is the code for "mainpage.xaml", the UI design code with some of the button's parameters:

```
<Page
x:Class="App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Hello world!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0"/>


</Grid>
```

Here is the code for "MainPage.xaml.cs" that contains the event handler for the button:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


namespace App
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        //The event handler
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
            Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello, World!");
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know:

1. Am I missing anything in my program? If so, what?
2. Does the current playback device selected for my computer affect whether the sound plays?
3. Is the problem caused by the event handler in general or the command itself?

Information that might be useful:

- There are no build errors that keep the program from running
- My operating system is Windows 10, version 1803 (Build 17134.286)
- The version of C# I am using is 7.3
- I am using Visual Studio 2017
- [This is the tutorial I followed to create my app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wire up the Click event and its handler. Either in XAML or in code behind.

In XAML,

```
<Button Click=“Button_Click” ...
```

In code behind (you need to give the button a name like btn)

```
btn.Click += Button_Click;
```